# Problema para publicar aplicativo com Microsoft Advertising

Tags: uwp, publicidade

Criei um programa em UWP versão paga e outro em versão Free que contém Microsoft Advertising.
Quando tento enviar o aplicativo para ser publicado me da um erro na versão Free.

Your package Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml specifies version 10.1707.2.0, but 10.0.0.0 is the minimum available version.

Já busquei no Google mas não achei nada de util!

Comment: Testou a segunda resposta dessa pergunta? É exatamente igual a sua: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323404/why-my-uwp-package-is-being-rejected

Comment: Nao estava encontrando, tem que ser pelo Console de Gerenciador de Pacotes. Acho que instalou o Microsoft Advertising Framework for XAML 10.1705.16001, vou fazer os testes aqui!!!

Comment: Sim, funcionou!

Comment: Porem, agora tenho que ver como colocar as publicidades no aplicativo. Pois nao funciona mais como estava antes!